# How do I add a custom legend to a graph in R?

Tags: r

I have been working in `pairs()` for this and am spending an embarrassingly long time trying to add a legend or use phantom notation to change the color of the species in the title to correlate with the points...any insight would be greatly appreciated! This is a problem.

```
# original code
pairs(iris[1:4], 
  main = "Width and Length (cm) of Iris's Petals and Sepals: Setosa, Veriscolor, Virginica", 
  pch = 24, bg = c("mediumorchid4", "mediumpurple1", "lightpink1")[unclass(iris$Species)], 
  upper.panel=NULL, labels=c("Sepal Length","Sepal Width","Petal Length","Petal Width"), 
  font.labels=1, cex.labels=2)
```

Comment: See `?legend`. To get the placement right, you might want to use `locator()` to get the (x,y)-coordinates (right-clicking to escape it and return back to the command-line). Then use the returned coordinates to place the legend, via something like `legend(x=0.7, y=0.8, ...)`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a better alternative, just in case the (not very good) accepted answer goes away:

```
pairs(iris[1:4], 
  main = "Width and Length (cm) of Iris's Petals and Sepals: Setosa, Veriscolor, Virginica", 
  pch = 24, bg = c("mediumorchid4", "mediumpurple1", "lightpink1")[unclass(iris$Species)], 
  upper.panel=NULL, labels=c("Sepal Length","Sepal Width","Petal Length","Petal Width"), 
  font.labels=1, cex.labels=2)

legend(x = "topright",legend = levels(iris$Species),
        pch = 24,pt.bg = c("mediumorchid4", "mediumpurple1", "lightpink1"),
        inset = 0.1)
```

Rather than using `locator` as Josh suggested, I just eyeballed a decent setting for `inset`.